# Крепкость и крепость

Tags: грамотная-речь

Тут на днях пришлось писать текст о сигаретах, так вот, в википедии мне попалось слово "крепкость" по отношению к сигаретам. А разве не крепость? Как правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, в профессиональном жаргоне чаще используется крепкость, если только речь не идет об алкогольных напитках. 
Тут просто два семантических ряда.
***Крепкость*** - от крепкий (сигареты, чай и проч.)
И ***крепость***, ***крепленый*** - от крепить - это почти исключительно в отношении вин.

Применительно же к *крепкому* алкоголю тоже по аналогии утвердилось "крепость", хотя это несколько спорно. С одной стороны такие напитки именно крепкие, не креплёные, с другой - процесс повышения их "градуса" имеет место, пусть и не называется креплением.

Но, повторю, все это имеет смысл только в отношении профжаргонов, на общелитературном языке слово "крепкость" лучше без особой нужды не употреблять.